piping docker logs to multiple processes
I'm grappling with an issue for the last few weeks.  I'm unable to explain why I don't get the logs in the third process when I pipe the logs from docker.  For eg.
$ echo "hello world!" | egrep -ai "hello" | sed -e 's/hello/Hello/'
Hello world!

As you notice, sed gets the line and can run the script.
sed in the following command doesn't receive the input.
# grep returns matching lines
$ docker-logs 87b7826c2828 |& egrep -ai "EventLogger"
2024-09-19 16:52:57,646 INFO [EventLogger]: xxxxxx

# It appears that sed is not getting any input
$ docker-logs 87b7826c2828 |& egrep -ai "EventLogger" | sed -s "s/EventLogger/Transform/"
# No output

I wonder why the output of egrep is not connected to the input of sed. I replaced |& with 2>&1 | as I noticed the same behavior on OSX with zsh and on Linux with bash.  Am I missing something here?

Add option -u to GNU sed and --line-buffered to GNU grep?

Btw.: egrep is deprecated.

Thank you. --line-buffered works. The man page of grep states that this can cause performance penalty. Any idea why the stdout is directed to stdin without this option?

do you need the grep .... sed will ignore all non matching lines anyway . also sed -s 's/EventLogger/Transform/I' will do a case insensitive substitution

You are right.  I don't need to use grep|egrep in between.  The objective was to demonstrate the problem and why the stdout from one is not connected to the stdin of the following process.
